# Apache Commons Compress unable to add hard link in tar

Tags: java, tar, apache-commons-compress

I have a set of files in which there are some hard links pointing to some of the files.
For Example:

```
/tmp/test/file1
/tmp/test/file1_Link
```

The `file1` is a file with size 1 MB.
`file1_Link` is a hard link pointing to `file1`

When I use the unix `tar` command to tar these both files , the resulting archive has a size of 1 MB (`mytar.tar`)

```
tar -cvf ../mytar.tar .
-rw-r--r--  1 bsarraf  189060905   1.0M Feb 11 22:06 mytar.tar
-rw-r--r--  1 bsarraf  189060905   2.0M Feb 11 22:10 files.tar
```

However when I use the apache commons compress and add all the files in the tar file, I get a tar with size 2 MB (`files.tar`).

This means in the tar the same file was added twice.

How can I add the hard link file in the tar as a hard link of the other file?

Comment: You didn't show your code. I believe you have to detect hard links and handle the link entry creation (within the tar file) yourself. `org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarConstants` contains type constants for both soft (`LF_SYMLINK`) and hard (`LF_LINK`) links.

Comment: Thanks @JimGarrison for your response. I was able to resolve the issue with some experiment.

Answer (score 3):

For others who might have the same issue, I was able to solve the issue with the following approach:
1. Identify if the file is a hard link, there are various ways to do this.
2. Once hardlinks are identified, use the following method to add the hardline file in the tar

```
private void addLinkFileToTar(TarArchiveOutputStream tar, File linkFile, File file, String base)
        throws IOException {
    String entryName = base + linkFile.getName();
    TarArchiveEntry tarEntry = new TarArchiveEntry(entryName, TarConstants.LF_LINK);
    tarEntry.setLinkName(base+file.getName());
    tar.putArchiveEntry(tarEntry);
    tar.closeArchiveEntry();
}
```

here linkFile is the hard Link file and file is the target File.